# Subclasses of a ViewController with a nib

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a ViewController that I've set up with outlet and a NIB.

This is my super class view controller.

I now want to create a subclass of this view controller as there is one method I would like to override.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

I've tried to do it but at the moment I've just got the functions in the superclass running in place of the actual class I want.

Any pointers?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I had done it correctly but had a typo in the overridden function.

Comment: Can you post your code of the derived VC?

Comment: How are you creating your controller? share some code

Comment: Sorry, a bit of code shared and some more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your super class functions not to run then you must override them. Just write the definition of the method you want to override and that will override it. The rest of the functions will be same as super class.

Comment: I have done this, I think the problem is actually loading the subclass from the nib of the superclass. The functions have been overridden, they are just not running.

Comment: you mean the actions of the nib in base class?

Comment: GAH! I was being an idiot sorry :( I had overridden the function with a typo and that's why it wasn't working :( sorry.

Comment: Please elaborate on what are you doing and what are you trying to achieve